# How to export React class getter with injectIntl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

This is my class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  get pageTitle() {
    const { intl } = this.props;
    return intl.formatMessage({id: 'messages_my_class_page_title'});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Dummy content
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MyClass.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired
}

export default injectIntl(MyClass);
```

**My page title appears when I put in a random text and don't use react-intl *injectIntl* function.**

I have 'react-intl' working fine for all other cases. Even for static properties using 'hoist-non-react-statics' library.

I am stumbled upon this one.

**Edit 1:**
I can fix it using

```
<FormattedMessage id="messages_my_class_page_title"/>
```

But I want to know how to use injectIntl way.

Comment: So, are you getting an error when trying to get the page title using react-intl? And if you do, what's the error message?

Comment: Hi Jaxx, I am not getting any error messages. Its a null return. I cant even console.log the output in getter as injectIntl creates a copy of the component.

Comment: If you remove the getter (i.e just have a `pageTitle()` method with the exact same content) and then invoke that method inside your component with `{this.pageTitle()}`, do you see the formatted title being displayed?

Comment: @Jaxx I am looking to find solution with the getter. Because the value is inherited and child class sets the value.

Comment: try withRef: true ?
https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/1084